# Oracle - Get all characters before the nth occurrence of a character

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to get a query where I get all characters from a string before the 'n'the occurence of a character.

Say I could have the following strings:

```
'123456,123456,123456'
'123456'
'123456,123456,123456,123456,123456,123456'
'123456,123456,123456,123456,123456,123456,123456'
```

Now I want my query to always return everything before the 5th occurence of the comma,

Result:

```
'123456,123456,123456'
'123456'
'123456,123456,123456,123456,123456'
'123456,123456,123456,123456,123456'
```

I've been trying with some substr or regexes, but I can't get my head around this.

Comment: does length of strings always be 6 nos?

Comment: The 'substring' (so the 123456) between the comma's is always the same amount of characters, so for this example we can work with 6.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[INSTR](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/olap.111/b28126/dml_functions_1103.htm#OLADM564) function has exactly what you need to find the position of n-th substring - see the occurrence parameter.

To get the part of a string till this location use SUBSTRING. 
To avoid the case when there is no Nth symbol, use NVL (or COALESCE).

For example (replace 5 with N and insert your columns):

```
SELECT NVL(
  SUBSTR(YOUR_COLUMN, 1,
    INSTR(YOUR_COLUMN,',',1,5) -1),
  YOUR_COLUMN)
FROM YOUR_TABLE;
```

Comment: Thanks! It seems I was already very close to this answer, with just some small differences.

Comment: Positions in strings are 1-indexed and while this would work you should be using `SUBSTR( your_column, 1, ...`.

Comment: Thanks! Corrected the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that:

```
define string_value='123456,123456';
select CASE 
            WHEN (length('&string_value') - length(replace('&string_value',',',null))) >=5 
            THEN SUBSTR('&string_value',0,INSTR('&string_value',',',1,5)-1)
            ELSE '&string_value'
        END as output
from dual;
```

output:

123456,123456

```
define string_value='123456,123456,123456,123456,123456,123456';
select CASE 
            WHEN (length('&string_value') - length(replace('&string_value',',',null))) >=5 
            THEN SUBSTR('&string_value',0,INSTR('&string_value',',',1,5)-1)
            ELSE '&string_value'
        END as output
from dual;
```

output:

123456,123456,123456,123456,123456

This will work event if the number of character between the commas is not always the same.